# How do I add an attribute (which is to be dynmamically named) to JS/ExtJS object?

Tags: javascript, extjs, javascript-objects

Consider the following requirement :

Lets say I have :  `var sampleObj = { };`

I want to add some attributes+values to this object. e.g. resultant obj is to be :

```
 sampleObj = 
   { 
    'att1' : 'value1', 
    'att2' : 'value2', 
    'att3' : 'value3' 
   }
```

Now I can easily to this by directly setting `sampleObj.att1 = 'value1'`, so on.

But the problem is I get the attributes names dynamically. Say names are in some string var, e.g. `attName = 'att5'`

`sampleObj.set/add(attName, 'value');` doesnt work.

If tried like `sampleObj.attName = 'value'`, it adds `'attName'` as attribute.

What I want is something like `sampleObj.${attName} = 'value'`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to access the property with variable name:

```
sampleObj[attName] = 'value';
```

Comment: Thanks!  Wasn't aware of this syntax. Didnt think it was that simple... :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [Ext.apply](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext-method-apply). You should also be able to use standard array type assignment such as sampleObj['attr1'] = 'value';

So in this case you would do something like:

```
var sampleObj = 
{ 
    'att1' : 'value1', 
    'att2' : 'value2', 
    'att3' : 'value3' 
}

var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel');
Ext.apply(panel, sampleObj);
```

Testing in the browser console (firefox):

```
var sampleObj = 
{ 
    'att1' : 'value1', 
    'att2' : 'value2', 
    'att3' : 'value3' 
}

sampleObj.att4 = 'value4';

sampleObj['att5'] = 'value5';

console.log(sampleObj);
```

Produced the following output:

```
att1" "value1"
att2" "value2"
att3: "value3"
att4: "value4"
att5: "value5"
```

So all methods above worked for me